# AngularJS: Get dates with suffix rd, th and st

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to format Date in Angular Java script?

**Code**

```
<p id="summaryHeader">Calendar of {{dt}}</p>
```

I get the value as 
`2014-06-05T12:38:42.744Z`

I tried this

```
<p id="summaryHeader">Calendar of {{dt|date:'MMMM dd'}}</p>
```

which gives me

`Calendar of June 05`

I need it as `Calendar of June 05th` or July 2nd and so on.. the rear `rd,th,st` is what I am looking for.

[Anuglar Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) are good but don't specify this formatting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for - http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/13/an-ordinal-date-filter-for-angularjs
A custom filter using the logic

```
app.filter('dateSuffix', function($filter) {
  var suffixes = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
  return function(input) {
    var dtfilter = $filter('date')(input, 'MMMM dd');
    var day = parseInt(dtfilter.slice(-2));
    var relevantDigits = (day < 30) ? day % 20 : day % 30;
    var suffix = (relevantDigits <= 3) ? suffixes[relevantDigits] : suffixes[0];
    return dtfilter+suffix;
  };
});
```

And a Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HiyQ9uvxQL3FRoj7hKB8?p=preview

Comment: I continued upon your example in my answer, but wanted to thank you and give you proper credit for the filter you created, nice work.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to have the ordinal indicator as a superscript, so used the following:

```
<div>{{amount}}<sup ng-bind="amount | ordinal"></sup></div>
```

Using the filter:

```
app.filter('ordinal', function() {
return function(number){
    if (isNaN(number) || number < 1){
        return '';
    } else if (number % 100 == 11 || number % 100 == 12) {
        return 'th';
    } else {
        var lastDigit = number % 10;
        if (lastDigit === 1) {
            return 'st';
        } else if (lastDigit === 2) {
            return 'nd';
        } else if (lastDigit === 3) {
            return 'rd';
        } else if (lastDigit > 3) {
            return 'th';
        }
    }
}
});
```

Note that this correctly renders 11**th**, 12**th**, 111**th**, 1012**th**, and not 11**st**.

Comment: You need a couple of minor fixes to get 10 (no ordinal) showing as 10th and 13rd to appear as 13th

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the date filter does not provide this formatting... I would suggest that you either write your own filter, or just do this:

```
Calendar of {{dt|date:'MMMM dd'}}{{getOrdinal(dt)}}
```

if you write your own, I would start with the one from angular as a baseline.

**EDIT** the idea of writing your own in the answer provided by guru is the approach I would take.

To expand upon the example he created, I would tweak it so that you can use this syntax:

```
Calendar of {{dt|date2:'MMMM ddoo'}}
```

Where `oo` is the ordinal suffix

I updated this representative [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGj08KzQrZTiCP4ubDOc?p=preview) to give you maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody that hits this question there is the project https://github.com/chrisiconolly/angular-all-ordinal-filters (full disclaimer: my own project) that will give you a ordinal number filter for angular.

Its used as so:

```
{{number | ordinal}} // 1 -> 1st
{{number | ordinalOnly}} // 1 -> st
```

It's fully tested and running through travis so it will remain stable.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your date in a [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) object like

```
$scope.dt = moment($scope.dt);
```

then do

```
<p id="summaryHeader">Calendar of {{dt.format("ddd Do")}}</p>
```

Other options may be better unless you already use `momentjs` elsewhere, just an option.

Comment: This looks like a great approach! I wonder, is it better to keep ALL dates in AngularJS as moment() object or as standard JS date?

Comment: @Dimitry momentjs is a large package and will add memory and performance overhead, so I suggest trying to use the native Date object where possible.  Also consider alternatives such as https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs - saying that, I've found momentjs very helpful!

Comment: tks! Will try! I guess for nodejs momentjs is great, but you're right for frontend every library adds up..

Answer (score 0):

While not my best work you can start with this as a baseline

http://plnkr.co/edit/v2RuF72A9OPpFj5fvN8A?p=preview